# Apache looks for index.php files in Laravel 5

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I am a begginer in Laravel and I am having troubles with Apache 2.2.15 on CentOS 6.5 and Laravel 5. I have searched for this error and I found some solutions for .htaccess and for httpd.conf but none of them are working and i get this error when trying to access "public/auth/register" or "public/auth/login" and even "/home":

```
    Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
```

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here is my httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The only page that works is the public/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to point apache to the `public` folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
  <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```